# develop or contribute to ubuntu community

Tags: application-development

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu development. I have developed many apps for Windows. My college and school uses only Windows. So, I'm very familiar with developing in Windows. But, when I wanted to switch over to Ubuntu, it was very difficult to adopt.

Now, I'm OK in using Ubuntu. I'm currently interested in doing some basic programs in Ubuntu so that I can start contributing in the coming years.

I know this is a weird silly question. I went through `developer.ubuntu.com`. But, it focuses only on mobiles. But, I need to develop for PCs. Not in cloud or web. Just a simple desktop application. I don't know where to start.

In google, I find a lot of stuff that leads mostly to `developer.ubuntu.com`. So, bare with me if this question is silly.

Also, I have basic knowledge in CSS, JavaScript, C, C++, Java

Answer (score 1):

For PC apps, you may try learning python as it will help you in many aspects. For developing linux apps, you can use python library pygtk (search for it online) for developing graphical interface for apps.
These are some links which may help you out:

http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/build-a-twitter-client-using-pygtk

http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/